# How to read specific data from an uploaded txt file on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need a client to upload a text file. Then I want to parse the text file such that only lines with the word "object" in it is the only thing left in the text file. I have successfully coded the uploading part. But need help coding how to parse out the lines with "object" not in it. My node js code is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ReadLine API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/readline.html) that's part of Node Core to iterate through the file line-by-line. You can use [`string.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to determine if your line contains the phrase you're looking for.

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

function filterFile(phrase, input) {
    return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var lines = [];
        let rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: input
        });

        rl.on('line', (line) => {
            if (line.includes(phrase, 0))
                lines.push(line);
        });

        rl.on('close', () => {
            let filteredLines = Buffer.from(lines);

            return resolve(fs.createReadStream(filteredLines));
        });

        rl.on('error', (err) => {
            return reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

---

#### Edit for Filtered Output Write Stream Example

We can take the resulting stream returned by `filterFile()` and pipe its contents into a new file like so

```
var saveDest = './filteredLines.txt');

filterFile('object', inputStream)
  .then((filteredStream) => {
    let ws = fs.createWriteStream(saveDest);

    filteredStream.once('error', (err) => {     
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });

    filteredStream.once('end', () => {
      console.log(`Filtered File has been created at ${saveDest}`);
      return Promise.resolve();
    });

    filteredStream.pipe(ws);
  });
```

Comment: Perfect answer, just make sure that the input is input: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/uploads/' + filename) becuase fstream is a write stream in my code.

Comment: @Baner see my update, I wrapped readline in a Promise returning function that takes a phrase to filter on and na input stream, it returns filtered lines as a stream.Readable or rejects if an error occurs.

Comment: Yup thank you for the answer. However, just for my knowledge, what is the second parameter in line.includes(phrase,0). What does 0 mean?

Comment: @Baner, 0 is the index in the string to begin the search for matching text.

Comment: Is there a way of saying if a line does not include this, then push?

Comment: @Baner `if (!line.includes(phrase, 0))`

Comment: any idea how to save the new parsed file into a folder? Right now I am printing the lines, but I wanted to save the file on my computer

Comment: @Baner just use `var ws = fs.createWriteStream('./filteredLines.txt');` and then pipe the output from the promise return by filteredFile into your new write stream. `.then((filteredStream) => { filteredStream.pipe(ws); });`

Comment: Would this go within the r1.on method? Maybe can you add this to the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Step : 1

Divide the line using --

```
var x='i am object\ni m object';
var arr = x.split('\n');
```

Step : 2

For each line, test with object regexp

```
var reg = /object/g
if(reg.test(<eachline>)){
   // write new line
}else{
  // do nothing
}
```